# How to filter List with multiple 'and' 'or' conditions

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to filter List on following SQL query format;

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM Tracker
 where (TrackProposalID = 6 and TrackRequestID = 0) or TrackRequestID = 16
```

**Linq**

I have tried this so far but getting syntax error;

```
listT = CType(listT.Where(Function(o) (o.TrackProposalID = 6 And o.TrackRequestID = 0) or (o.TrackRequestID = 16)).ToList
```

Comment: is the C# tag really neccessary? it seems to me that you want vb.net

Comment: Is that your actual line of code? Your CType doesn't seem to have a type provided which is an obvious problem and leads me to believe that either your question isn't reflective of your actual problem or that your actual problem is just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C#

```
listT = listT.Where(o => (o.TrackProposalID == 6 && o.TrackRequestID == 0) || o.TrackRequestID == 16).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
listT = listT.Where(x=>(x.TrackProposalID == 6 && x.TrackRequestID == 0) || (x.TrackRequestID == 16).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = listT.Where(x=>(x.TrackProposalID == 6 && x.TrackRequestID == 0) || x.TrackRequestID == 16).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = listT.Where(x => x.TrackRequestID == 16 || (x.TrackProposalID == 6 &&  x.TrackRequestID == 0))
```

if you won't make ToList(). it will execute every calls to "result". so i recomend make ToList().